# Getting started with Assets Framework - assets.cms.gov

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, accessibility, web-frontend

I've seen some recommendations about using Assets Framework (assets.cms.gov) for accessibility. My understanding is that Assets provides a framework on top of Bootstrap and jQuery UI, among others, to achieve 508 a11y compliance.

I have attempted to download the latest version of the Framework (3.4.1) from the website (assets.cms.gov), but have been unable to get a sample started using the instructions on their getting started and UI components pages.

Can anyone confirm if the project is still supported and maintained? Can anyone provide a sample on getting started with the project?

Ideally I would like to just get a plain sample page with js, css, and the jQuery UI accessible datepicker.

Thanks,

V

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Assets Framework, but you can achieve Section 508 compliance using [U.S. Web Design Standards](https://standards.usa.gov/).

> ... typography and color recommendations that are 508 compliant...
>
> We created tools that seamlessly meet the standards of 508 accessibility, from colors to code.
>   ...
>
> All of the code is 508 compliant, so it’s accessible to everyone..

To learn more about the project, check out this [blog post](https://18f.gsa.gov/2015/09/28/web-design-standards/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep an eye on the standards.usa.gov site. They don't have an accessible date/calendar picker at the moment.

Comment: I don't know the state of Assets any longer, but if you are just looking for a date picker one option is this jQuery UI example by Hans Hillen: http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_datepicker Parts of it were supposedly folded into jQuery, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: We ended up rolling our own solution based on some examples from the Assets framework datepickers, the Hans Hillen info, and Deque university https://dequeuniversity.com/library/aria/date-pickers/sf-date-picker